# Hector_Slam (Autonomous Navigation)

Tags: slam, gazebo, navigation, ros-kinetic, hector-slam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am new to navigation and generally in ros and I am trying to use hector_slam metapackage for autonomous navigation. I am using ROS Kinetic.
I have a 3 wheel robot with a lidar on which I have created as a urdf model and I am using gazebo for simulations.
Currently, I have managed to use the hector_mapping node to create a map and visualize it through rviz. For the building of the map, I used teleoperation to move the robot.
Now I am lost, because I am trying to implement autonomy on my robot. What packages of the hector_slam meta will help me with that and generally where should i start ?

Thank you for your time and for your answers in advance,

Chris

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/241616/hector_slam-(autonomous-navigation)/) by [patrchri](https://answers.ros.org/users/26728/patrchri/) on ROS Answers with karma: 354 on 2016-08-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pallavbakshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/28889/pallavbakshi/) on 2017-01-24**:
@patrchri Hey, I saw your question about Kinect v2 earlier. I wish to do autonomous navigation using Kinect v2. Unlike you, I am not using LIDAR. I am totally lost about how to go about it. How can I convert depth information to laserscanner data? PLEASE HELP! I plan to use gmapping though. Thanks!

**Comment by [patrchri](https://answers.ros.org/users/26728/patrchri/) on 2017-01-24**:
I haven't worked with the Kinect v2 since November and my project wasn't related to point cloud data,but you can get point cloud data from this [tool](https://github.com/code-iai/iai_kinect2) .Then use these data with this [package](http://wiki.ros.org/pointcloud_to_laserscan) to get 2D laser points

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found about the [hector_navigation](http://wiki.ros.org/hector_navigation) stack.

---

Originally posted by [patrchri](https://answers.ros.org/users/26728/patrchri/) with karma: 354 on 2016-08-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [burf2000](https://answers.ros.org/users/28716/burf2000/) on 2017-01-19**:
Hey there, did you get it working as I need to do the following

**Comment by [patrchri](https://answers.ros.org/users/26728/patrchri/) on 2017-01-19**:
Yes, I have managed to get results in simulations...I have completed succesfully an autonomous_exploration behavior...Still haven't tried it on hardware though

**Comment by [burf2000](https://answers.ros.org/users/28716/burf2000/) on 2017-01-20**:
Is there a package you can install via apt-get or do you need to download from source

**Comment by [patrchri](https://answers.ros.org/users/26728/patrchri/) on 2017-01-20**:
I don't know ...maybe there is via APT, but I installed from source and I didn't meet any major problems

**Comment by [scopus](https://answers.ros.org/users/8561/scopus/) on 2017-08-29**:
hi, @patrchri, I also want to use hector_exploration_planner in hector_navigation, However, I found that hector_exploration_planner couldn't drive robot, i.e., the robot doesn't move. I also can't found where the velocity that drives the robot is computed and published. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are asking specifically about Hector, but is there a constraint that requires you to use Hector? I ask because the Navigation stack documentation has a nice tutorial that provides instructions essentially starting from scratch. It's great way for beginner to quickly* get a robot moving on its own.

http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials

It will show you gmapping slam (unlike Hector Slam, it requires odometry info with the lidar to build map) instead of Hector to build a map, then introduce AMCL and move_base for the localization and autonomous navigation and obstacle avoidance.  If your robot has a means of getting odometry (wheel encoders, IMU, other?) I think the navigation stack is a good place to start.

DISCLAIMER: I have used Hector SLAM for map building, but tried nothing more with it. Did not attempt navigation with it. I am not advocating Navigation Stack over Hector Navigation, I am advocating for the thorough tutorial that comes with the Navigation Stack. YMMV.

*quickly is a relative term...

---

Originally posted by [billy](https://answers.ros.org/users/26871/billy/) with karma: 1850 on 2016-08-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [patrchri](https://answers.ros.org/users/26728/patrchri/) on 2016-08-15**:
Thank you for your in-detail answer...I chose hector because my robot does not have odometry. That's why I am trying autonomous navigation with that meta.

**Comment by [patrchri](https://answers.ros.org/users/26728/patrchri/) on 2016-08-15**:
Could I combine the hector_mapping and generally the hector localization with the move_base of the navigation stack ?

**Comment by [billy](https://answers.ros.org/users/26871/billy/) on 2016-08-15**:
A few hybrid options: 1 - You could use the laser scan matcher as replacement for odometry while using navigation stack. There are other threads on that topic you should check out. 2 - I don't think it matters where map comes from. I think any localization method would work if if has map/odom tf out